# When and how should a question be retagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, etiquette

Hi, sorry I'm sure this has been asked before but I'm having trouble finding it.

I just got over 500 rep so I can retag questions now, and I was just wondering when/how to go about this.  To get specific, would it be correct to re-tag a question in the following circumstances?:

1. Replacing mis-spelled tags with correctly-spelled ones
2. replacing ones with 'less popular' names to the commonly used ones, for example 'winmo' to 'windows-mobile' (and if so, how do you know the popular ones?  Just by searching on the Tags page?)
3. Changing the tag to something more specific - for example if someone tags their question 'ruby-on-rails' but the question is purely about the ruby language and not the rails framework, so retag it to 'ruby'?  (not so sure about that one)
4. Adding a more relevant tag - so if someone post a WinMo question but just tags it 'C#', add the 'windows-mobile' tag

Comment: I think common-sense prevails on this one plus all of your above points.

Comment: I'm liking the retag!  Very appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all fine reasons to retag. Keep in mind you don't *have* to retag. If you're unsure, just leave a post as is.