# Interviewing Stack Overflow users about their use of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, etiquette, answers, research

I'm looking to interview a few Stack Overflow users for a study concerning the the process of answering questions online. Specifically, I'd like to hear about their experiences answering, editing and retagging questions on the site.

Alas, I can't think of a really good way to find users to interview. Contacting people directly strikes me as a bit stalkerish, not to mention spammy. People *have* asked questions similar to mine via Meta Stack Overflow, but they tend to receive rather laconic answers, e.g.,

- [When and how should a question be retagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58796/when-and-how-should-a-question-be-retagged)
- [How do SO'ers select questions to answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68589/how-to-soers-select-questions-to-answer)

Moreover, many of my questions have highly individual answers, e.g., "When answering a question, how do earlier answers factor into your answer?"

Any thoughts on a good way to find willing interviewees? (Is this it?)

Comment: FWIW, I'm up for an interview, either here or directly. My E-Mail address is in my profile

Comment: I'm pretty sure the nature of your study will influence how you want to contact people. Do you want a random sampling of users or are you after very specific users? You might be able to get Jeff to post on the SO blog about your study and get volunteers that way (depending on how he feels about your study), or you might just want to cold-call a select few people who have contact information in their profiles/websites.  I think a lot of us on Meta would be willing to answer questions; I know that I've been cold-e-mailed before to talk about SO and I'm usually in the mood to talk about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably is the one non-intrusive way to look for people. Yet there is a obvious drawback when inviting people for an interview voluntarily: you get a biased sample. So depending on what you want to do with the data, there is no other way than to come up with a significant random dataset of users and contacting them cold. Well, let's say lukewarm, as you announced it here and e form a great community.